# How to comment out classes inside class=""? Is this even possible?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to comment out specific classes inside the HTML (`<div class="" ...>`)?

For example:

```
<div data-group="group1" data-container="true" class="container-lg d-flex /* slider */ p-0">
```

Where in this example the class "slider" should be (temporarily) excluded from the class list.

[UPDATE]

Based on the comments I understand the way of thinking, so I go for the solution Lee Taylor mentioned. When I want to disable a specific class assignment, I just add a prefix to that class. For example:

```
<div class="slider container"...
```

becomes:

```
<div class="disable-slider container"...
```

Life could be so easy if the mind is thinking too complex :-D
Thank you all for thinking with me!

[/UPDATE]

This would make life a lot easier, in my opinion, in these ways:

- You don't have to switch to your style sheet and go searching for the matching class, commenting out and switch back again to the code.
- It's clear for everyone that you just exclude the complete function, which - if named clearly - gives other developers a better overview.
- For testing purposes you could use this as (style) modules, which are enabled/disabled in a snap! Again, no more hopping between screens/tabs/windows.
- Easier debugging. Just comment out some classes and you've got the source of the problem in no time.
- It stimulates developers to use recognizable and clearly named classes

Currently I copy the whole element/row, comment this out and add a comment and then paste the copied row below. Then I remove classes from this line of code.

Most of the time this doesn't get updated, so you can't see it as a reliable backup if you're debugging.

I know for sure that such would be possible with JS, but why? (Also changing the HTML structure with JS gives a lot of headaches when it comes to layout shifts and not everyone has the possibility to make use of server side scripting.) Such should exist HTML in my opinion.

Am I the only one who has this in mind?

Comment: There's nothing stopping you adding a common prefix to the class you don't want to be processed. For example, `slider` becomes `ZZZ-slider`. But hard to see why you have this problem.

Comment: Thanks @LeeTaylor! sometimes things could be so simple :-D I just go for a prefix like "dis-"

Comment: You can do it with the style attribute maybe thar helps

Answer (score 2):

Per the [HTML Specification on the class attribute](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#classes):

> When specified on HTML elements, the class attribute must have a value that is a set of space-separated tokens representing the various classes that the element belongs to.

Here is the [definition for space-separated tokens](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#set-of-space-separated-tokens):

> A set of space-separated tokens is a string containing zero or more words (known as tokens) separated by one or more ASCII whitespace, where words consist of any string of one or more characters, none of which are ASCII whitespace.

> A string containing a set of space-separated tokens may have leading or trailing ASCII whitespace.

Therefore, no, you should technically not be allowed to comment out class list members in any way.  If any implementation of the specification does allow this, then it is undefined behavior and should not be depended upon.

Comment: Aren't CSS comments allowed anywhere where there is white space?

Comment: @A Haworth No, you are confusing CSS Syntax with HTML Syntax.  Classes are simply a list of whitespace-separated identifiers.

Comment: @sn02 - I sor tof agree, except it's the way browsers let you unselect a property setting - ie it works

Comment: @AHaworth That is CSS inspecting which is browser-specific and not related to the HTML Specification on the `class` HTML attribute.

Comment: Interesting - so browsers are happy with it (they seem to be on tests) but the spec doesn't allow it. W3C validator doesn't object but that of course is not a final abiter. I confess to having used it and not realised it was 'illegal'.